# Requested resource does not support http method "PUT"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I'm using AttributeRouting with my Web API (MVC 4).

Why does this work?

```
    [AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
    [PUT("api/v1/tokens/current")]
    public MemoryToken UpdateToken([FromBody] DeviceTokenViewModel viewModel)
    {...}
```

And this one does not?

```
    [PUT("api/v1/tokens/current")]
    public MemoryToken UpdateToken([FromBody] DeviceTokenViewModel viewModel)
    {...}
```

Error message: The requested resource does not support http method "PUT". 
Why do I have to explicitly accept the PUT verb?

I'm just confused because something similar with POST works just fine (I don't have to specify the accepted verbs):

```
 [POST("api/v1/tokens")]
 public MemoryToken CreateToken()
 {...}
```

From various other posts I believe it has to do with the setting in my web.config. The web server section currently looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="AttributeRouting" path="routes.axd" verb="*" type="AttributeRouting.Web.Logging.LogRoutesHandler, AttributeRouting.Web" />
</handlers>
```

I tried a couple things like removing WebDav and stuff. But nothing worked so far (unless explicitly allowing the PUT verb in the annotation).

Oh, I am using Visual Studios built-in development server.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

In this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) they describe the POST method as being the default if none of the actions match. So that's why it still works for your CreateToken() method without an HttpPost attribute .

- You can specify the HTTP method with an attribute: AcceptVerbs, HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPatch, HttpPost, or HttpPut.
- Otherwise, if the name of the controller method starts with "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then by convention the action supports that HTTP method.
- **If none of the above, the method supports POST.**

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your explanations. Yes, I know that I can specify the allowed HTTP methods (see the first snippet). And I thought so too that if I just rename my method from "UpdateToken" to "PutToken" (though this doesn't sound nice), I would't need the [AcceptVerbs] attribute. But I do. Maybe this is due to the AttributeRouting (mentioned in the first sentence of my post). It's actually not a big deal. I can live with setting the [AcceptVerbs] attributes where ever I need them. Won't be that much. I was just hoping I could forget about this by tweaking my web.config a bit. Thanks again!

Comment: @IngmarBode, I tried to reproduce your symptom, but could not--I changed the method name to Put and to PutToken and it worked in both cases. Please retry and consider accepting this answer.